# scala - delegate implementation design pattern (without reflection ?)

Tags: java, scala, design-patterns

I would like to expose a public API (a kind of Runnable) and let users implement it, and then execute that code against our servers (given the class name containing the code to run). Users provide a jar containing their implementation and should not have access to implementation details.

Below is a snippet illustrating the issue.

The **public API:**

```
package mypackage

trait MyTrait {
  def run(i: Int) : Unit
}
```

A sample **user's implementation:**

```
package mypackage

object MyImpl extends MyTrait {
  override def run(i : Int) : Unit = {
    println(i)
  }
}
```

The **server-side code running the user's code:**

```
package mypackage

import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

object MyTest extends App {

  val m = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
  val module = m.staticModule("mypackage.MyImpl")
  val im = m.reflectModule(module)
  val method = im.symbol.info.decl(ru.TermName("run")).asMethod

  val objMirror = m.reflect(im.instance)
  objMirror.reflectMethod(method)(42)
}
```

The above code works (printing "42"), but the deisgn seems ugly to me.

In addition it seems unsafe (class instead of object, object that does not exist or does not implement the correct interface).

What's the best way to achieve this ?

I am using Scala 2.11.8.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Why not simply use `MyTrait` interface?

Comment: How should I call it in the server-side code ?

Comment: I don't see how it being run on the server is relevant here.

Comment: My users provide a jar containing their implementation, and then my server (big cluster that may run that code in a distributed way). Users should not have access to implementation details.

Comment: I think you should look into `ServiceLoader` from Java standard library: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: adamwy That seems yo be exactly what I am looking for. Thanks for your help